# Using TorBrowser with MadMAC's and DNS Crypt products?

Tags: dns

Has anyone here used the TorBrowser with either the products MadMAC's or DNS Crypt?

I'm currently testing or rather trying out both to determine if they offer me any added anonymity to my web surfing. I'm still a newbie about DNS leaks and using the TorBrowser (correctly) as well as VPN's and still have a lot to learn. With that said, does anyone know if using MadMAC's and/or DNS Crypt at the same time I'm using my TorBrowser will help my anonymity on web surfing or am I just making things worse?

Re: MadMAC's, in summary it's a script to randomize your machine's MAC address (and host name) in Windows on every boot. It was discussed on the IronGeek website. http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/changemac. Here's the download. http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/madmacs-mac-spoofer.

Regarding DNS Crypt, for those unfamiliar, it helps eliminate DNS leaks and appears to eliminate DNS leaks whether I'm connected to a VPN or even just a regular high speed cable connection with my ISP. Please note I have observed when using the website "DNS Leak Test" to test my TorBrowser for DNS leaks, I tend to see lots of DNS leaks and become concerned, but maybe that is normal because of the way Tor is set up; there's going to be these DNS leaks and maybe am I just over reacting based on how Tor works?

I do have to say when using DNS Crypt, I'm not sure how much data is going back to OpenDNS to track, though. Couple of other things I do is when I'm not using DNS Crypt, I usually change my Windows 7 preferred and alternate DNS Server Address for IPv4 and IPv6 to an OpenNIC or other public one listed on ShieldsUp website instead of having these configured automatically, which means the DNS Server Addresses are my ISP's. I also turned off my Teredo connection for added security.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the MadMac part:

> The MAC address is only visible on your local network. You don't need
>   to hide it.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67268/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-mac-address-of-a-host-using-tor (Answer by @ThoriumBR)

--

For DNSCrypt part:
A properly configured TBB (default) will tunnel all DNS resolutions and DNSCrypt is not needed.

--

Overall: Neither products will increase your anonymity.

Comment: For the paranoids out there: if you want to further increase your security, try the live operating systems tails (tails.boum.org) and whonix (whonix.org).

Comment: Additionally, if you are on a public wifi connection or if someone sniffs your home router and gets access they can get your mac address, I would most definitely spoof your mac address when on public wifi or on a non-hardened / untrusted router / ISP.

Comment: ^ I think both tails and whonix has a mac spoofer built in. :)